# Use a particular div that have a background-color without affecting the body's background

Tags: html, css

What I'm trying to do is to have a white background with the logos centered on the page. Could someone help me?

```css
body {
    background-image : url(black.jpg); 
}
#bg {
    background-color: white;
    width: 1500px;
    height: 1000px;
}
#logos{
    margin-right : auto;  
    margin-left : auto;
}
#logos img{
    width: 250px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <h1>Hello</h1>
 <div id= "bg">
   <div id="logos">
    <img src="./logos/sb.png">
    <img src="./logos/fb.png">
   </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: If you want a white background don't set a `background-image` in the body tag. Instead do `body { background-color: #FFF; } `. There are lots of ways to centre elements on the page [shown here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, hope it helps ;)

```css
body{
    background-image : url(black.jpg); 
}
#bg{
    background-color: white;
    width: 1500px;
    height: 1000px;
}
#logos{
    margin-right : auto;  
    margin-left : auto;
    text-align:center;
}
#logos img{
    width: 250px;
    height: 100px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <h1>Hello</h1>
 <div id="bg">
  <div id="logos">
   <img src="./logos/sb.png">
   <img src="./logos/fb.png">
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: It works. Thanks! :) But, may I ask why did you use inline-block in img?

Comment: w3schools explain inline-block really well. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp "inline-block elements are like inline elements but they can have a width and a height.". In my experience they work really well in responsive environments.